# How to change the font style of selected text in rich edit control devexpress

Tags: c#, devexpress

How to change the font style of selected text in rich edit control.
As in richTextbox we use selection font to do this.But in richText edit control What should i have to done to get same output as richTextBox.

As an example.
In richtextbox we write something and click in the B (bold) button and then the selected textstyle will be Bold.

But I can't do it with rich edit control and button.I have written following code with respect to the Bold button.

```
editconrol1.Font = new Font(editcontrol1.Font.FontFamily, editcontrol1.Font.Size, FontStyle.Bold)
```

But the problem is, it changes the whole document as SelectionFont.

By clicking bold button, It should change the selected text to Bold and If again click on bold button selected text should change back to normal like MS word

Kindly review and give feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [How to: Change Formatting of Selected Text](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/5890/Controls-and-Libraries/Rich-Text-Editor/Examples/Formatting/How-to-Change-Formatting-of-Selected-Text) documentation article which
demonstrates how you can get the selected text in code, and modify its attributes:

```
CharacterProperties cp = document.BeginUpdateCharacters(document.Selection);
cp.FontName = "Comic Sans MS";
cp.FontSize = 18;
cp.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
cp.BackColor = Color.Snow;
cp.Underline = UnderlineType.DoubleWave;
cp.UnderlineColor = Color.Red;

// Finalize modifications   
// with this method call  
document.EndUpdateCharacters(cp);
```

The [Document.Selection](https://documentation.devexpress.com/OfficeFileAPI/DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.API.Native.Document.Selection.property) property is used to obtain the [DocumentRange](https://documentation.devexpress.com/OfficeFileAPI/DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.API.Native.DocumentRange.class) object, representing the user selection.

A complete sample project is available at https://github.com/DevExpress-Examples/winforms-richedit-document-api-e5219